# Accessing localy hosted wordpress site from remote machine

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, wamp

I have a WORDPRESS MU (multisite) configured on my computer and when i enter **localhost** in the browser address bar i can access the panel.

I tried entering my IP address (**aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd**) and it worked but i saw that it was replaced with **localhost** in the browser address bar.

So i tried to access it from a remote machine entering my address and it gets replaces with **localhost**. Obviously there is no server running on the remote machine from which i try to access my WORDPRESS so no webpage is loaded.

Any solution for how this can be fixed?

P.S.

I use WAMP server and my Wordpress wp-config.php file looks like this:

```
define('WP_DEBUG', true);

define('WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true);

define('MULTISITE', true);
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', false);
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'localhost');
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/');
define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);

define('WP_HOME','http://aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd');
```

Comment: WP also stores urls in the database.  Further, on a multi-site install, each site's url is determined from the database.  Probably the simplest method is to run [SRD3](https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/) on your database, replacing "localhost" with "aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd".  BE SURE to backup your database - if you make a typo, it can vape your DB!

Comment: Thanks you for the support. I did it manually :)

Comment: You can't do it manually.  WordPress stores information in [serialized](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) form in the database, and if you alter the contents of any of the serialized data manually, you will likely break that record.  That is why you need the SRDB tool I mentioned.

Comment: Nope. The configuration and especially the host name are not in serialized form so it worked like a charm. Maybe if the site is full of content then i would need the tool. By the way how to use this tool u mentioned in case i really need it?

Comment: Not "Nope".  My statements are factual.  You either have missed some locations with the url, or else you haven't changed them all.  And the tool is super easy to use: download it, install it in your root folder (should be in the same directory as wp-config.php), browse to that page, and follow the prompts.